# Sorting string arrays based on the number present in the element

Tags: javascript

I have to sort a string array based on the number.

**Example**

```
["1.READ","10.CREATE","3.sfg","2.dfd","12.dqwe"];
```

**Desired Result**

```
["1.READ","2.dfd","3.sfg","10.CREATE","12.dqwe"];
```

**My Code**

```
var arr = ["1.READ","10.CREATE","3.sfg","2.dfd","12.dqwe"];
var arr2 = arr.map( a => a.split('.').map( n => +n+100000 ).join('.') ).sort().map( a => a.split('.').map( n => +n-100000 ).join('.') );
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `split` and convert the first element to `Number`

```js
var arr = ["1.READ", "10.CREATE", "3.sfg", "2.dfd", "12.dqwe"];

var arr2 = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  return Number(a.split(".")[0]) - Number(b.split(".")[0]);
});

console.log(arr2);
```

---

The code above will also sort the first variable. If you you only want `arr2` to be sorted, you can:

```js
var arr = ["1.READ", "10.CREATE", "3.sfg", "2.dfd", "12.dqwe"];

var arr2 = [...arr]; //Spread the array so that it will not affect the original
arr2.sort((a, b) => {
  return Number(a.split(".")[0]) - Number(b.split(".")[0]);
});

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could split and take only the first part. Then take the delta for sorting.

```js
var array = ["1.READ", "10.CREATE", "3.sfg", "2.dfd", "12.dqwe"];

array.sort((a, b) => a.split(".")[0] - b.split(".")[0]);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: @NinaScholz as clean as it can be :)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
var arr = ["1.READ","10.CREATE","3.sfg","2.dfd","12.dqwe"];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.split('.')[0] - b.split('.')[0];
});

console.log(arr)
// ["1.READ", "2.dfd", "3.sfg", "10.CREATE", "12.dqwe"]
```

This answer base on built in array sort function, with customizable compare logic.
Check this out for more detail: [Javascript Array Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Cheers,